# Не отображается текст на кнопках tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть код:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Калькулятор")
window.geometry("400x600")
window.resizable(False, False)
canvas = Canvas(window, width=400, height=400, bg='white')

font_settings = ("Times New Roman", 40, "")
virtualImg = PhotoImage()


resultLabel = Label(window, text="0", font=font_settings, image=virtualImg, width=375, height=75, compound=CENTER, bg="grey77", anchor="e")
resultLabel.place(x=10, y=10)

oneButton = Button(window, text="1", font=font_settings, image=virtualImg, width=75, height=75)
oneButton.place(x=134, y=276)

mainloop()
```

При его запуске на кнопке не отображается текст, а точнее 1. помогите пожалуйста. спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте параметр `compound=CENTER`:

```
oneButton = Button(window, text="1", font=font_settings, image=virtualImg, width=75, height=75, compound=CENTER)
```

Comment: Получилось, работает!